# How to repair the grub on debian

Tags: debian, grub

I am loading Linux (Debian Lenny) on VirtualBox but there is apparently something wrong with the GRUB. When I start the system, a grub menu appears:

[image]

Then I run the following commands:

> root (hd0,0)
>   kernel /vmlinuz root=/dev/hda1 ro quiet
>   initrd /initrd.img
>   boot

After the system boots, how should I continue to repair the grub file?
Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: How about [`update-grub`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=update-grub&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+4.0+etch&format=html&locale=en) (as root)?  This should rebuild your `grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 2):

First (for future visitors), if you can't manage to boot into your system, pop in a Debian rescue CD or USB drive, mount your root partition at `/mnt`, and open a terminal and run

```
chroot /mnt
```

so that you can type commands in your installed system. If you have a separate `/boot` partition, type `mount /boot` to mount it.

You should have a file called `/boot/grub/menu.lst`. If you don't, run `update-grub` to create an initial file. The file contains “magic” comments, which the `update-grub` command transforms into actual Grub directives. Look for the following two lines (which begin with a `#`) and edit them if they don't match what worked for you:

```
# kopt=root=/dev/hda1 ro quiet
# groot=(hd0,0)
```

Once you've edited these lines, run `update-grub` (again, if you had to run it once to create the file).

If you prefer to write `menu.lst` manually (which is only necessary in odd setups), here's how the section to boot Linux would look like:

```
title           Debian GNU/Linux
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /vmlinuz root=/dev/hda1 ro quiet
initrd          /initrd.img
```

Comment: Why would this fix anything?

Comment: @steveantwan Grub consists of multiple pieces. The first piece needs to know where the second piece is, and the first piece can't read the filesystem. Running `update-grub` writes the first piece outside the filesystem and embeds the location of the second piece based on information in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`. For whatever reason, something in the asker's system is not up to date, and following this answer should rewrite the parts of grub that are outside the filesystem with a correct configuration.

Comment: However, note that this answer was written a long time ago, and is not necessarily valid for modern versions of Grub.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can load an alternative kernel? You can use TAB to look for other available kernels? The error message can mean you didn't have a disk driver compiled into the kernel or as a module.

Comment: I could manage to boot the system. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Just add the kernel parameter to your grub line. The root=... ro helps me sometimes, too.

Comment: But maybe change ro to rw?